# How to create glowing rgb grid checkbox

Tags: css

Trying to replicate a youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXkGEWJl_-k) i saw and it triggered my ocd .This is what [what](https://codepen.io/samuellucy/pen/QWLaEpr) I have achieved so far , had no idea what Im doing honestly as Im so bad and clueless at css. Any css connoisseur out there that can help me out? Also feel free to fork this and make it better (not that it's my idea to begin with) and share it with the world by all means.

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    &:after {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      margin-top: 8px;
      margin-left: 1px;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      border: 1px solid silver;
      border-radius: 0.25em;
      background: rgb(47, 50, 68);
      background-size: 400%;
    }

    &:checked:after {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, #03a9f4, #f441a5, #ffeb3b, #03a9f4);
      filter: blur(5px);
      background-size: 400%;
      border-radius: 30px;
      animation: animate 8s linear infinite;
      z-index: 1;
    }
  }


@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    background-position: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 400%;
  }
}
```

Comment: now what u want to create do want to have same design as he showed on the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXkGEWJl_-k)  @samuellucy96

Comment: The main thing i want is just for the rgb to glow as the same as the one on the video, anything else is second or third. i probably should research more on animate,  color blend , shadow , etc before asking this question but my ocd ...

Comment: Define your problem more accurately?

Comment: Yes , my bad , let me start from the foundation . First of all how do i change an element color to multi-color(rgb) , overtime/periodically ,  with css only .I tried searching on google but I can't seem to find any . If you have any source on this feel free to link to me .I will highly appreciate and give it a good read. Thank you.